# I'm tring to pre-populate my edit page in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to pre-populate my form fields with the title and its content that can be edited.

I have tried all possible ways but it still doesn't show the initial value.

view.py:

```
class EditPageForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

def edit_page(request,pre_title):
    
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # dictionary for the intial values
        intial_dict = {
        "title": pre_title,
        "content": util.get_entries(pre_title)
        }
        # create a form instance :
        form = EditPageForm(request.POST,initial=intial_dict)
        
       # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            util.save_entries(title,content)
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('wikiapp:index'))

        # if data is not valid we'll return the form with error message
        else:
            return render(request,"encyclopedia\edit_page.html",{
                "form": form
            })

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    return render(request,"encyclopedia\edit_page.html",{
        "form": EditPageForm()
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prepopulate the form in case of the get method. You do it for the post method only.

```
def edit_page(request,pre_title):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance :
        form = EditPageForm(request.POST)
        
       # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            util.save_entries(title,content)
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('wikiapp:index'))
    else:
        intial_dict = {
            "title": pre_title,
            "content": util.get_entries(pre_title)
        }
        form = EditPageForm(initial=intial_dict)
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    return render(request,"encyclopedia\edit_page.html",{
        "form": form
    })
```